# How to customize vim-syntastic?

Tags: python, vim, syntastic, pyflakes, vim-syntastic

I've written a python script. My vimrc contains:

```
Plug 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'
let g:syntastic_python_checkers=['pyflakes']
```

and I'd like to turn this kind of error into warning:

```
File.py|214 error| local variable 'rank_last_c' is assigned to but never used
```

and my code is like that:

```
def run():
    ...
    find(something)
    ...
def find(n):
    ...
```

Clearly, the function 'find(n)' is defined.
But there's error like that:

```
File.py|149 error| undefined name 'find'
```

What should I do to customize my syntastic?

Comment: You appear to have two different questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flake8 and you will be able to [ignore errors](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/3.2.1/user/ignoring-errors.html) easily.

But with your second example, I bet it's something in the lines of

```
class MyClass:
    def run():
        find(something)

    def find(n):
        ...
```

so you deserve the error...